# Find the shortest path in a wire mesh with N and M units

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you have a wire mesh which is N by M units long, made up of unit square with wire at the edges. (So there are N+1 parallel wires all M long and, perpendicular to these, M+1 all N long).

An ant starts off at the bottom left corner of this grid (co-ordinates (0,0) and crawls on the wires the shortest possible distance to reach the top-right corner (N,M). How long is the shortest route.

How many different shortest routes are there? (Namely, find a formula in terms of N and M) You might want to try this for small values of N and M and see if you can work out how the number for (N,M) relates to those for (N,M-1) and (N-1,M)

Comment: Is this an assignment? Where are your efforts?

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework to me. What have you tried so far? What are your ideas? If it’s a homework and you’re stuck, take a look at the “shortest path” problem and the Dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is apparently about a homework assignment, and doesn't display any effort to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest route is N+M units long , number of such routes are (n+m)Cn or (n+m)Cm where nCr is Binomial coefficient

Answer (score 0):

To get the shortest path from a bottom most point to top most point you need to travel only two path if exist , that are top & right.

Hence the recurrence relation is :-

```
paths(N,M) = paths(N-1,M) + paths(N,M-1).
```

Solve the recurrence using Dynamic Programming.

More precisely :-

There are total paths equal to binary numbers which are of N+M bits with precisely `N 0's` and `M 1's` which is `(M+N) C N`  (choosing N items from M+N items)